# CRM Address table and it relation

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation

Hi I want to ask about I have this DBD for my CRM I am trying to have the addresss in one table(customer  and Employee Address) and both customerID  and Employee ID are guid I have in address table FK is associate_ID to store the id (customer.ID or Employee.ID) just want to ask if is ok to do it like that ?[image]

Answer (score 1):

A customer is a role played by a Party, which is an Individual or Organization (or Automated Agent).

Same with employee.

A party can have zero or more addresses, parties can share the same address, and addresses can exist without parties.

Your data model should look like this:

PARTIES -< ROLES

PARTIES -< PARTY_ADDRESSES >- ADDRESSES

```
create table parties (
  party_id bigint primary key,
  type text not null, --this should point to a party_type table in real life
  name text not null,
  ...party-type-specific into
);

create table party_roles (
  party_role_id bigint primary key,
  type text not null, --this should point to a party_role_type table in real life
  party_id bigint not null references parties(party_id),
  ...role-type-specific info...
);

create table addresses (
  address_id bigint primary key,
  type text not null, --this should point to a address_type table in real life
  ...address-type-specific info...
);

create table party_addresses (
  party_id bigint references parties(party_id),
  address_id bigint references addresses(address_id),
  role text not null, --this should point to a party_address_role table in real life

  primary key (party_id, address_id, role_id)
);

--demo data:

insert into parties values
(1, 'INDIVIDUAL', 'Neil'),
(2, 'ORGANIZATION', 'Acme, Inc');

insert into party_roles values
(1, 'EMPLOYEE', 1),
(2, 'CUSTOMER', 2);

insert into addresses values
(1, 'MAILING', '123 Main Street'),
(2, 'MAILING', '456 Bay Street');

insert into party_addresses values 
(1, 1, 'HOME'),
(2, 2, 'HEADQUARTERS');
```